# numpy histogram boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to sky subtract astronomical images by creating histograms of the pixel intensities in each image, and then seting the sky value equal to the intensity of the bin with the highest frequency. Then the idea is to subtract this sky value from each pixel within that frame.IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3651469 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3651468

```
#sciFlat is a list containing three images in array form.

sciFlat = np.asarray(sciFlat)
minpix = min(sciFlat.flatten())
maxpix = max(sciFlat.flatten())
rng = int(maxpix-minpix)
#These are histogram ranges, now loop through each image.
#Sky subtract science images.
sciSky = []
for i in range(3):
    hf = np.histogram(sciFlat[i].flatten(), bins=rng, range=(minpix,maxpix))
    skyval = hf[1][hf[0] == max(hf[0])]
    print(skyval)
    skySub = sciFlat[i] - skyval
    sciSky.append(skySub)
```

I expect the code to complete successfully as numpy.histogram should return hist (a flattened array of size n) and bin_edges (1D array of length n).

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

```
142     hf = np.histogram(sciFlat[i].flatten(), bins=rng, range=(minpix,maxpix))
143---> **skyval = hf[1][hf[0] == max(hf[0])]** <----
144     print(skyval)
145     skySub = sciFlat[i] - skyval
```

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3651469 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3651468

Comment: What is `hf.shape`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is simply your logic that fails in the loop, writing out histogram output:

```
for i in range(3):
    hist, edges = np.histogram(sciFlat[i].flatten(), bins=rng, range=(minpix,maxpix))
    skyval = edges[hist == max(hist)]
    print(skyval)
    skySub = sciFlat[i] - skyval
    sciSky.append(skySub)
```

Histogram provides you with edges of the values, what you most likely want is the midpoint of the edges:

```
for i in range(3):
    hist, edges = np.histogram(sciFlat[i].flatten(), bins=rng, range=(minpix,maxpix))
    mids = edges[:-1] + np.diff(edges)/2
    skyval = mids[hist.argmax()]
    print(skyval)
    skySub = sciFlat[i] - skyval
    sciSky.append(skySub)
```

by setting mids instead of edges, your histogram has the same dimensions. To illustrate the difference of edges and mids:

```
sciFlat = np.random.uniform(0,15,100)
hist, edges = np.histogram(sciFlat, bins=(sciFlat.max()-sciFlat.min()).astype(int), range=(sciFlat.min(), sciFlat.max()))
mids = edges[:-1] + np.diff(edges)/2

hist.size
Out[33]: 14

edges.size
Out[34]: 15

mids.size
Out[35]: 14

plt.hist(sciFlat, bins=(sciFlat.max()-sciFlat.min()).astype(int), range=(sciFlat.min(), sciFlat.max()))
plt.plot(mids[hist.argmax()], hist.max(), marker='*', ms=20, c='C3', zorder=1)
plt.plot(mids, hist, 'o', zorder=2, c='C1')
```

Star denotes the largest midpoint, as you see, it is between the edges:
[image]